# Why can't the import com.google.android.gms.plus be resolved?

Tags: android

I'm trying to integrate Google sign-in in my app but the import `com.google.android.gms.plus` says that the symbol `plus` can't be resolved, why? Is it because of the version I'm using?s

This is my app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hadi.do2get"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my project gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'


 }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I've tried many tutorials but none of them works. Google's own tutorial gives me errors too.

Comment: You need compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'`

Comment: do I need to add it or edit?

Comment: You need to add it for Google Plus libraries.

Comment: Ok thank you it worked :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try doing

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
```